# What is the right way to join these 2 Spark DataFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, outer-join

Let's assume I have 2 spark DataFrames:

```
val addStuffDf = Seq(
  ("A", "2018-03-22", 5),
  ("A", "2018-03-24", 1),
  ("B", "2018-03-24, 3))
.toDF("user", "dt", "count")

val removedStuffDf = Seq(
  ("C", "2018-03-25", 10),
  ("A", "2018-03-24", 5),
  ("B", "2018-03-25", 1)
).toDF("user", "dt", "count")
```

and in the end I want to get a single dataframe with a summary statistics like this (ordering doesn't matter, actually):

```
+----+----------+-----+-------+
|user|        dt|added|removed|
+----+----------+-----+-------+
|   A|2018-03-22|    5|      0|
|   A|2018-03-24|    1|      5|
|   B|2018-03-24|    3|      0|
|   B|2018-03-25|    0|      1|
|   C|2018-03-25|    0|     10|
+----+----------+-----+-------+
```

It's quite clear that I can simply rename the "count" columns at "step 0", so to have dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
val df1 = addedDf.withColumnRenamed("count", "added")
df1.show()
+----+----------+-----+
|user|        dt|added|
+----+----------+-----+
|   A|2018-03-22|    5|
|   A|2018-03-24|    1|
|   B|2018-03-24|    3|
+----+----------+-----+

val df2 = removedDf.withColumnRenamed("count", "removed")
df2.show()
+----+----------+-------+
|user|        dt|applied|
+----+----------+-------+
|   C|2018-03-25|     10|
|   A|2018-03-24|      5|
|   B|2018-03-25|      1|
+----+----------+-------+
```

But now I'm failing to define "step 1" - namely, to determine the transform that would zip together df1 and df2. 
From the logical standpoint `full_outer` join brings all the rows I need in a single DF, but then I need to merge duplicating columns somehow:

```
df1.as('d1)
  .join(df2.as('d2),
        ($"d1.user"===$"d2.user" && $"d1.dt"===$"d2.dt"),
        "full_outer")
.show()

+----+----------+-----+----+----------+-------+
|user|        dt|added|user|        dt|applied|
+----+----------+-----+----+----------+-------+
|null|      null| null|   C|2018-03-25|     10|
|null|      null| null|   B|2018-03-25|      1|
|   B|2018-03-24|    3|null|      null|   null|
|   A|2018-03-22|    5|null|      null|   null|
|   A|2018-03-24|    1|   A|2018-03-24|      5|
+----+----------+-----+----+----------+-------+
```

How can I merge these `user` and `dt` columns together? And, overall - am I using the correct approach to solve my problem or is there a more straightforward/efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the columns to be joined for the two DataFrames have matching names, using `Seq("user", "dt")` for the join conditions will result in the merged table you want:

```
val addStuffDf = Seq(
  ("A", "2018-03-22", 5),
  ("A", "2018-03-24", 1),
  ("B", "2018-03-24", 3)
).toDF("user", "dt", "count")

val removedStuffDf = Seq(
  ("C", "2018-03-25", 10),
  ("A", "2018-03-24", 5),
  ("B", "2018-03-25", 1)
).toDF("user", "dt", "count")

val df1 = addStuffDf.withColumnRenamed("count", "added")
val df2 = removedStuffDf.withColumnRenamed("count", "removed")

df1.as('d1).join(df2.as('d2), Seq("user", "dt"), "full_outer").
  na.fill(0).
  show
// +----+----------+-----+-------+
// |user|        dt|added|removed|
// +----+----------+-----+-------+
// |   C|2018-03-25|    0|     10|
// |   B|2018-03-25|    0|      1|
// |   B|2018-03-24|    3|      0|
// |   A|2018-03-22|    5|      0|
// |   A|2018-03-24|    1|      5|
// +----+----------+-----+-------+
```